# How to set a default value for a flag in cobra

Tags: go, default, go-cobra

Is there a way to define a default value for a flag `(VarP)` in the cobra?

```golang
func (f *FlagSet) VarPF(value Value, name, shorthand, usage string) *Flag {
    // Remember the default value as a string; it won't change.
    flag := &Flag{
        Name:      name,
        Shorthand: shorthand,
        Usage:     usage,
        Value:     value,
        DefValue:  value.String(),
    }
    f.AddFlag(flag)
    return flag
}
```

I could not find a default value in the function definition.

Comment: Can you list what you've tried and considered, or what your other constraints are?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways — it's unclear what's been tried from the question.

- The easiest way is to use one of the dozens of type-specific `FlagSet` helper methods. For example, [`FlagSet.StringVarP`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/pflag#StringVarP)
- If you're using custom logic to load flags that don't work well with that, there is [`FlagSet.AddFlag`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/pflag#FlagSet.AddFlag) which takes a [`Flag`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/pflag#Flag). This type has a field for default value.
- Then there's what you mentioned in your question, using [`FlagSet.Var`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/pflag#FlagSet.Var) and related methods, by implementing a custom type with that interface. If you go this route, you're responsible for defining what a "default value" is. The `Value` interface provides a method to `Set` a value and output what the current value is. If you want a default value, return it when nothing has been set in your custom type.